# I have my image set to resize but how do I make the image resize from the center as opposed to the upper left hand corner?

Tags: jquery, html

This is the code that I am using to increase the size of my image on rollover but it resizes from the top left as opposed to the center of the image. How do I resize from the center of the image?

```
    <script>
        $('img').hover(function() {//Hovering
          $(this).animate({
              width: '50%',
              height: '50%',
          }, 400);//Speed of animation in ms
      }, function() { //Not hovering
          $(this).animate({
              width: '25%',
              height: '25%',
          }, 400);
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no jQuery functionality to do that, but you could do it manually by  adjusting the top and left position as you resize the image to give the effect of it resizing from the center.

To do that you probably need to position absolutely so the left and top take effect like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqD7u/)

Comment: that is exactly what i am looking for thank you ... what is this fiddle program that you used this is the first time i have seen it?

Comment: @Erith It's a website that "renders" Html, Js and css. It's very useful to show snippets of code, and it's free. If I helped you, please accept the answer

Comment: How would you affect this code so that when I roll over the image the z-index changes so that when I have an image next to an image they dont push each other around?

Comment: you could change the z-index too, take a look a this http://jsfiddle.net/yqD7u/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is code that I have created that isnt working but gets to the point of what I want to do.

```
$('img').hover(function() {//Hovering
          $(this).animate({
              width: '50%',
              height: '50%',
              $('img').css('zIndex', '2');
          }, 400);//Speed of animation in ms
      }, function() { //Not hovering
          $(this).animate({
              width: '25%',
              height: '25%',
              $('img').css('zIndex', '0');
          }, 400);
      });
```